# Upper invisible part of a Canvas cannot be printed

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, printing, scrollviewer

An app has a Canvas with the size of an A4 page embedded in a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer > 
    <Canvas Name="PageCanvas"  Width="21cm" Height="29.7cm">
```

That works pretty fine. Now when the user wants to print, the app does this:

```
PrintDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
     dlg.PrintVisual(this.PageCanvas, "Document");
```

**Problem:** The printout always only starts with the **visible** part of the Canvas.

So when you scroll down, the invisible part on **top** of the canvas is **not visible** on the printout.

However, and this it really strange, the invisible part on **bottom** of the Canvas is **always visible** on the printout!

So what's wrong here ?

Comment: According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be2edad6-f075-4295-ab22-3657eba78043/how-to-print-the-entire-of-a-wpf-window-that-scrolls?forum=wpf) on MSDN, you can just set the code to run the scrollbar to the top before it prints.

Comment: @Tofystedeth Ah yes. Well, that would of course be a simple solution, didn't think of that ;) A little bit "clumsy" in my eyes, but well ok, it's important that it works. Post it as an answer, then I can upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround for it that I found [here on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be2edad6-f075-4295-ab22-3657eba78043/how-to-print-the-entire-of-a-wpf-window-that-scrolls?forum=wpf) is to just set the scrollviewer back to the top before calling the code to print it.

If you want something a little less hacky, I worked on a project a couple years ago where I laid out a template for the data as a XAML window with binding, then turned the window into a FixedDoc, which can then be printed directly, or turned into an xps file for batch printing later.  The conversion looked something like this.

```
private FixedDocument ConvertToDoc(DocInfo pageData)
    {
        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        PageContent content = new PageContent();
        FixedPage page = new FixedPage();
        DocTemplate printTemplate = new DocTemplate(pageData);
        page.Children.Add(printTemplate);
        ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)content).AddChild(page);
        fixedDoc.Pages.Add(content);
        return fixedDoc;
    }
```

Where DocTemplate is the xaml page I laid out, and pageData is the model object that it binds to.  You might be able to do a similar thing with your canvas.